# What's the difference between using remember in assignment vs in delegation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Compose and wondering what's the difference between these two lines of code:

```
val stateValue = remember { mutableStateOf("value") }
```

And:

```
var stateValue by remember { mutableStateOf("value") }
```

In the first method, the way we update the state is by changing the value like so:

`stateValue.value = "new value"`

But when using delegation wer'e just changing the variable's value directly:
`stateValue = "new value"`

How then after re-composition the state is still "remembered" after we just overridden the existing value that had the `remember` function?

Comment: Even in first case `statevalue = "new value"` should cause re-composition. Compose uses positional memoization and `GroupArray` under the hood , and stores an instance of the remeber state, and then compares with the new instance. If there is a difference in either the state or the previous instance then there is a re-composition. Check https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd&ved=2ahUKEwjk2fDkysTwAhXYcn0KHTRVDAIQjjgwAHoECAQQAg&usg=AOvVaw3EwEeFE-OMpffLKHfVJzcC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegation -as the name says- allows to delegate the getter and setter to a separate object.

So when you do `stateValue = "new value"` on the delegated property, you are *not* "overriding the existing value that had the remember function".
What happens is that the assignment syntax actually calls the `setValue()` operator *on* the property delegate (the instance returned by the call to `remember` that was done during initialization of the property).

Take a look at the documentation to learn more about delegated properties:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html